# Edge Animate: Animation scales wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, adobe-edge

I am very new at javascript so maybe my question is very idiotic.
I want to get a javascript animation woking, which where generated in Edge Animate.
The problem is that it just don't want to be scaled in the actual size of the browser window.
All scaling Tutorials i have watched ended up with the same result maybe one of you pros could help me... 
Here is the link of the Page described before: http://simondesign.at/os/html1.html 
P.s. The script is in a "span" in the "body" section...
thank you everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to resize an Adobe Edge animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773600/is-it-possible-to-resize-an-adobe-edge-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching each element's
Width and height to be in percents 
Instead of px?
This is the first step to get the animation to scale.