# scale to fit edge animate stage composition (version 2014.1.1)

Tags: jquery, scale, adobe-edge

I would like to fit my edge composition to fill the **complete viewport** while being centered horizontal and vertical.

It should be similar to the css property `background-size: cover;`.

I stumbled over a few tutorials like this: http://sarahjustine.com/2013/04/08/create-scale-to-fit-projects-with-adobe-edge-animate/ , but it doesn't work for the version 2014.1.1

Does somebody got an solution or the same issue?

Comment: Here is the solution for my issue, if someone needs it:
https://gist.github.com/dhelbig/4950b962a039158d7e81

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to resize an Adobe Edge animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773600/is-it-possible-to-resize-an-adobe-edge-animation)